# DAX - Count rows from previous day and the day before

Tags: powerbi, dax

I want to see an increasement or decreasement in data and I'm not sure how I create a measure from previous day data and another measure from the day before in order to see an increasement or decreasement in data from the day before the previous day.

I use the following syntax:

```
Ufordelt = CALCULATE(COUNTROWS(TICKET),TICKET[owned_by] = 1,USERELATIONSHIP(DIM_DATO[Opprettet dato], TICKET[created_at]))
```

How do I filter this measure to only count data from previous day, and the other measure from the day before the previous day?

Answer (score 1):

Assuming that you are using a **date table** you can create a calculated column in the date table for the **date offset**. You can then use this calculated column in measures that use **relative** **time** to the current date.

Here is an example formula for a date offset column:

`DateOffset = DATEDIFF(TODAY(),'Calendar'[Date],DAY)`.

Then you can use the DateOffset column as a filter in your `CALCULATE` function. Using your example code and by the help of variables the measure could look something like this:

```
Ufordelt =
var n_rows = 
    CALCULATE (
        COUNTROWS ( TICKET ),
        TICKET[owned_by] = 1,
        USERELATIONSHIP ( DIM_DATO[Opprettet dato], TICKET[created_at] )
    )
var yesterday = CALCULATE(n_rows, 'Calendar'[DateOffset] =  -1)
var ereyesterday = CALCULATE(n_rows, 'Calendar'[DateOffset] =  -2)

return yesterday - ereyesterday
```

This measure now calculates the difference between yesterdays count and the day before yesterdays count.